# why is that the simple use of setState method not working in the componentDidMount() method

Tags: reactjs

For some Goddamn reason a simple update of state using the `setState()` method is not working and I think I've tried everything, like using arrow functions for the method, using a dictionary, and when I do console log in the `render()` function of the `is_loading` state of component it still is for some Goddamn reason unchanged.

```
import React from 'react';
import { 
    BrowserRouter as Router,
    Switch,
    Route,
    Link,
} from 'react-router-dom';

import './App.css';
import './bootstrap-5.0.0-beta3-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import './bootstrap/css/overwrite.css'

import TestComponent28 from './core/DjangoIntegration';


export default class App extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            data: [],
            is_loading: 0
        };
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        this.setState({
            is_loading: 1
        }, () => console.log(this.state));
    }

    render(){
        console.log(this.state);
        return (
            <Router>
                <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-primary">
                    <div className="container-fluid">
                        <a className="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
                        <button className="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                            <span className="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                        </button>
                        <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
                            <ul className="navbar-nav">
                                <li className="nav-item">
                                    <Link to="/" className="nav-link">Home</Link>
                                </li>
                                <li className="nav-item">
                                    <Link to="/about" className="nav-link">About</Link>                                    
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </nav>

                <Switch>
                    <Route path="/about">
                        <About/>
                    </Route>
                    <Route path="/">
                        <Home data={this.state['data']} loading={this.state['is_loading']}/>
                    </Route>
                </Switch>
            </Router>
        );
    }
}

function Home(props){
    console.log(props);
    console.log(props['loading']);
    return (
        <div className="App">
            <TestComponent28 {...props}/>
        </div>
    );
}

function About(){
    return (
        <h1>About</h1>
    );
}
```

Comment: What isn't working as expected? I don't really see an issue in your code so I wonder if there is just a misunderstanding of how React state updates work. What are you trying to do with this `is_loading` state?

Comment: I don't see any issue with your code, please try sharing a *running* codesandbox, or similar, that *actually* reproduces the issue you see, or at least provide more details about what ***your*** code is doing differently than your snippet. See [Minimal, Complete, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). I still suspect you have a misunderstanding with how React state updates work and are not interpreting unintentional side-effect of console logging in the `render` method correctly.

Comment: ```function Home(props){
    console.log(props);
    console.log(props['loading']);
    return (...);```

Comment: because state refuses to update from 0 to 1 the props I pass to the component `Home` still is 0

Comment: React doesn't refuse to update state. Please try to include all relevant code in your question and try to not waste people's time. You've yet to demonstrate a reproducible code example.

Comment: @DrewReese there I've updated the code that is the whole of it technically, for you to get the idea of what I am talking about

Comment: Copy/pasted into a running [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/why-is-that-the-simple-use-of-setstate-method-not-working-in-the-componentdidmou-3s74o). I see normal react state updates and several unintentional side-effect logs. Fixed the logging in `Home` and removed the other incorrect loggings.

Comment: finally found the problem i was overriding the `shouldComponentUpdate()` without any code blocks inside. Anyway thank you for considering to help

Answer (score 0):

> ***For the first time when the component mounts `is_loading: 0`. Then after component mounts you are calling `setState` function to update the state. So, after updating the state the component re-rendered. As a result, it `console.log()` `is_loading: 1` with updated value of the state.***

---

Try:

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: [],
      is_loading: 0
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState(
      {
        is_loading: 1
      },
      () => console.log(this.state.is_loading) // 1
    );
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.state); // {data: Array(0), is_loading: 0} & {data: Array(0), is_loading: 1}
    return (
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/about">
            <About />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/">
            <Home data={this.state.data} loading={this.state.is_loading} />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}
```

Live demo: [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-feistel-gwvk6?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: sorry for just removed the space between `set` and `State`. Code still doesnt work for some reason

Comment: `console.log(this.state);` inside `render()` function updating the `state` from `{data: Array(0), is_loading: 0}` to `{data: Array(0), is_loading: 1}`

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-feistel-gwvk6?file=/src/App.js See live

Comment: yeah tried it the first time of course the state is `{data: Array(0), is_loading: 0}` and still when state is updated in `componentDidMount()` the result is still `{data: Array(0), is_loading: 0}`

Comment: @MigRiveraCueva Are you trying to console log the state right after updating it?

Comment: @RashedRahat I console logged it in the `render()` method ```render(){
        console.log(this.state);
        return (
            ...
        );
    }```

Comment: `setState()` works `async` way. I hope you know what is it. To get the updated `state` pass a `callback` as second argument of `setState` func. Check my updated answer.

Comment: @MigRiveraCueva For the first time when component mounts `is_loading: 0`. Then after `componentMount` you are calling `setState` to update state. So, after updating component re-render. As a result, it console `is_loading: 1` with updated value of the state.

Comment: that is the problem I am trying to solve even after `setState()` the state of `is_loading` is still 0 and not 1

Comment: This is not a problem. It should be as the way of React. If this really bothering you then use `componentWillMount` instead of `componentDidMount` to get rid from it. See the live demo https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-feistel-gwvk6?file=/src/App.js when `componentWillMount` has used.

Answer (score 0):

At least you have a syntax problem:

```
    this.set State({
        is_loading: 1
    });
```

should be

```
    this.setState({
        is_loading: 1
    });
```

Also, I believe you should do something like:

```
(this.state.is_loading)?
            <Router>
                <Switch>
                    <Route path="/about">
                        <About/>
                    </Route>
                    <Route path="/">
                        <Home data={this.state.data} loading={this.state.is_loading}/>
                    </Route>
                </Switch>
        </Router>
          :
                   { // Do what your program needs to do
                     // after componentDidMount is over
                   }
```

Shouldn't  this.state.is_loading = 0  after componentDidMount is done? If this is the case, it will be needed:

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        data: [],
        is_loading: 1
    };
}
```

Comment: sorry for just removed the space between `set` and `State`. Code still doesnt work for some reason